# R sequence generation without boundaries

Tags: r, sequence

```
> seq(0.15, 0.85, length.out = 4)
[1] 0.1500000 0.3833333 0.6166667 0.8500000
```

I get a sequence of 4 numbers which are equidistant and boundaries(0.15, 0.85) are also included

How I can generate a sequence with boundaries not included ?

I don't see any such method available in documentation: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/seq.html

Comment: What is your expected output? if you want just the middle values, you can just use `seq(0.15,0.85,length.out=4)[-c(1,4)]`

Comment: Yes, that is one option, but I am looking for more simpler way, especially because the value of `length.out` comes from variable

Comment: Though I can use `seq(0.15, 0.85, len = pieces)[-c(1,pieces)]`

Comment: Aint there any other way through parameters or options ?

Comment: I don't think there is any parameter to do so at least in `base R`. I think you are overthinking something that can be simply solved with the code you just added yourself!

Comment: @boski: You are right, Please add it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no parameter that controls this in `base R`. You can work around this issue by using the following code:

```
seq(0.15,0.85,length.out=4)[-c(1,4)]
[1] 0.3833333 0.6166667
```

In case `length.out` is given by a variable:

```
a = 4
seq(0.15,0.85,length.out=a)[-c(1,a)]
[1] 0.3833333 0.6166667
```